# comparing the digits of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: python, if-statement

A 3-digit number will be generated with the random module and it has to be compared with a 3-digit number input.

Sample Comparison:

Random number is = `579`

My Input = `591`

The digit `5` is in the same place. Since it is in the same place, the computer needs to print `+`

Both numbers have `9`, but they are in different places. In this case `-` should be printed

Note: The digits must be a different 3-digit number

```
import random

a = int (random.randint(1,9))
b = int (random.randint(0,9))
c = int (random.randint(0,9))

if (a != b and a != c and b != c):
    while True:
        x = int (random.randint(1,9))
        y = int (random.randint(0,9))
        z = int (random.randint(0,9))
        if (x != y and x != z and y != z):
           estimate = x,y,z
           estimate = input("Enter Your Estimate:") 
        else:
            print("The figures of the numbers should be different") 
        if (a == x):
            print("+")
        if (b == y):
            print("+")
        if (c == z):
            print("+")
        elif((a == x and b == y) or (a == x and c == z) or (b == y and c == z)):
            print("++")
```

I tried to do it using conditional expressions, but I didn't continue anymore because there were lots of possibilities.
(My goal in asking this question is to find a more practical way)

Comment: `x`, `y`, and `z` have nothing to do with the estimate that you enter. They contain 3 random digits.

Comment: Hard to imagine a more confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```
import random

def generate_number():
    a = random.randint(1, 9)
    b = random.randint(0, 9)
    c = random.randint(0, 9)
    while a == b or a == c or b == c:
        a = random.randint(1, 9)
        b = random.randint(0, 9)
        c = random.randint(0, 9)
    return str(a) + str(b) + str(c)

def compare_numbers(target, guess):
    for i in range(3):
        if target[i] == guess[i]:
            print("+", end="")
    if target != guess:
        print("-", end="")
    print()

target_number = generate_number()
print("The Number to be Estimated is =", target_number)
user_guess = input("Enter Your Estimate: ")
compare_numbers(target_number, user_guess)
```

Comment: The only problem is that the number to be estimated appears.I'll take care of that, too.There are no other problems.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As the saying goes... "there are many ways to skin a cat".

So, this...

```
import random

def generate_number():
    # sample 3 different digits in the inclusive range 0-9
    # result may have a leading zero
    return random.sample(range(10), k=3)

target_number = generate_number()

while True: # keep guessing
    v = input('Enter your estimate: ')
    # validate user input
    if len(set(v)) == 3 and v.isdecimal():
        output = []
        for a, b in zip(map(int, v), target_number):
            if a == b:
                output.append('+')
            else:
                if a in target_number:
                    output.append('-')
        if output.count('+') == 3:
            print('You guessed it')
            break
        print(''.join(output) or 'No matches')
    else:
        print(f'{v} is not a valid guess')
```